# why does deadlock not happen

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

> Deadlock describes a situation where two more threads are blocked because of waiting for each other forever. When deadlock occurs, the program hangs forever and the only thing you can do is to kill the program.

why deadlock does not happen in example producer consumer problem given below:

I wonder why call wait method in synchronized block does not causing deadlock  when synchronized object is waiting for release of lock from other thread ?

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class WaitAndNotify {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        var th1 = new Thread(new Producer(list));
        var th2 = new Thread(new Consumer(list));
        th1.start();
        th2.start();
    }
}

class Producer implements Runnable {

    private List<Integer> list;
    private final Integer MAX_SIZE_LIST = 5;

    public Producer(List<Integer> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (;;) {
            synchronized (this.list) {
                if (list.size() == MAX_SIZE_LIST) { // check list is full or not
                    try {
                        System.out.println("list full wait producer");
                        list.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                var randNumber = rand.nextInt();
                System.out.println("produce number => " + randNumber);
                list.add(randNumber);
                list.notify();
            }
        }
    }

}

class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private List<Integer> list;

    public Consumer(List<Integer> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (;;) {
            synchronized (this.list) {
                if (list.size() == 0) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("list empty consumer wait");
                        list.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("consume number <= " + list.remove(0));
                list.notify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure, but it is possible that `Consumer` runs first.

Answer (score 3):

You probably think, that `Consumer` will block at `list.wait()` and Producer will block at `synchronized (this.list)`.

It works, because `list.wait()` releases the ownership of `list` inside a `synchronized` block. After `wait` returns, the thread acquires the ownership again.

See [Object.wait()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait())

Answer (score 0):

As we have already discussed here Deadlock did not happen because of the use of `synchronized block, list.wait() and list.notify()` methods.

Here is a nice example of deadlock : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html